# Publish graphic icon into geoserver from QGIS

Tags: qgis, geoserver, style, icon

I want to publish graphic icon (point) into geoserver by using maki style. Below is the coding,

```
<UserStyle>
  <se:Name>streetlight_u4</se:Name>
  <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    <se:Rule>
      <se:Name>Single symbol</se:Name>
      <se:PointSymbolizer>
        <se:Graphic>
          <se:ExternalGraphic>
            <se:OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="file:///maki/park-alt1-15.svg"/>
            <se:Format>image/svg+xml</se:Format>
          </se:ExternalGraphic>
```

But, the result turns like below:-

[image: result after publish the style]

Which is the actual graphic point is like below :-

[image: original style to publish]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you copied over the file to the Geoserver? You will have to put it in the `<geoserver_dir>\Workspaces\<workspaceName>\styles` folder

Comment: yes, i already upload the svg file and apply the style in geoserver, and the result turn square shape

Answer (score 0):

Your url `file:///maki/park-alt1-15.svg` starts with a `/` so GeoServer is searching in the root of the **file system**. If you want it to look in the styles folder then you should just use the file name as shown [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/points.html#point-as-graphic). If for neatness you chose to use a sub directory just use the sub directory name followed by the file name `subdir/file.png`

Comment: hai Ian, i have delete the file:/// and publish back,   <se:OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="maki/park-alt1-15.svg"/> but the result is same. i put file:/// because when validate the style turns error like this:- java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for ExternalGraphic: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute